# Unable to acquire db connection from Trac?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, trac, apache-bloodhound

Attempting to install [Apache Bloodhound](http://bloodhound.apache.org) (which is built atop Trac) on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 server.

I have followed [their installation guide](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall) precisely (for Postgres).

#### Error output from `bloodhound_setup.py`

```
Error: TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds.
```

#### Web interface

```
TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds.
              (OperationalError: could not translate host name "jr5@localhost" to
               address: Name or service not known
```

---

How do I get this to work?

Comment: is postgres running - can you connect to it?

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect to it via the `psql` client and run `\l` wherein I was able to verify the existence of the `bloodhound` database.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed frustrating.  I have had this problem on a couple of occasions, and the answer was never PostgreSQL related.  The first time it turned out to be a mod_wsgi setup error.  I changed my setup to use the instructions I found here:  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac.  Pay attention to the block about Trac instances "bleeding" over into other instances.

The other time it was related to trac and PAM authentication setup.  In that case, I abandoned libapache2-mod-auth-pam, and went with libapache2-mod-authnz-external.

In both cases, this error message cleared up on it's own without changing anything about PostgreSQL.

Sorry for the non-answer, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your password contains characters that must be escaped in the database connection string: `:`., `/` or `@`. See [DatabaseConnectionString](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracEnvironment#DatabaseConnectionStrings) for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was the problem. Thanks for the reference. Won't be testing it out now though; I have moved to JIRA.